# flask web ,current_user.role is None ,but table roles is not None

Tags: python, database, web, flask

```
class Role(db.Model): 
    __tablename__ = 'roles' 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    default = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, index=True)
    permissions = db.Column(db.Integer)
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='role', lazy='dynamic')

class User(UserMixin, db.Model): 
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    def can(self, permissions):
        print(self.role) #None
        return self.role is not None and (self.role.permissions & permissions) == permissions

@main.route('/',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = PostForm()
    print(current_user.role) #None
    print(current_user.can(Permission.WRITE_ARTICLES)) #False
    if current_user.can(Permission.WRITE_ARTICLES) and form.validate_on_submit():
        post = Post(body=form.body.data, author=current_user._get_current_object())
        db.session.add(post)
        return redirect(url_for('.index'))
    posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.timestamp.desc()).all() 
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, posts=posts)


sqlite> .tables
alembic_version  posts            roles            users
sqlite> select * from roles;
1|Administrator|0|255
2|Moderator|0|15
3|User|1|7
```

there is data in roles, but  print(current_user.role) is None,and When I call the can function in class User, print(self.role) is also None.

I can't understand why self.role is None?

Comment: output of `select * from "user"`?

Comment: from user? is't users?          sqlite> select * from user;      Error: no such table: user                                                                                          
       sqlite> select * from users; 
  
  
 1|1@1.com|a||pbkdf2:sha256:50000$RfTgXGZF$9a39224d6ace3e595f687c301a0372a42f0525caa572333d003a15f1de367e6e|1|kiudou|beijing|Thinking And Creating|2017-12-28 05:44:50.501491|2018-01-05 09:38:53.961966|